aiogram download excel file to user as a file
I have a little project which is automate work task with telegram.
I use aiogram 3.5 version

I need upload excel file, which contains several sheets as a dict , sheet names as a dict keys, information on them as a pandas dataframes.
manupulate over dict and dataframes on it.
updated, changed dict need to be written back to excel file, and send it to user
I have problem, in 3th task. I can't find way how to write and send written file to user.
PS. new excel file should be temprorly. I don't need store additional storage from server.
I rovide code, please if have some suggestions or advise, solution be kind. share it. thanks for advance.

#function for write updated excel_data dict to excel
def process_excel_data_to_bytesio():
    try:
        # Create a BytesIO buffer
        buffer = io.BytesIO()

        # Write the updated DataFrames to the buffer
        with pd.ExcelWriter(buffer, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            for sheet_name, df in excel_data.items():
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
                print(f"{sheet_name} is written")
        # Seek to the beginning of the stream
        buffer.seek(0)
        return buffer
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error processing Excel file: {e}")
        return None

@file_router.callback_query(F.data == "download_ip_file")
async def download_updated_ipfile_touser(query: CallbackQuery):
    try:
        if is_admin(query.from_user.id):
            await query.answer(" Faylni serverdan qabul qilib oling\n yuklanmoqda...", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

            # Process the Excel data to a BytesIO object
            buffer = process_excel_data_to_bytesio()
            await query.message.answer("ok", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

            # Check if the buffer was processed successfully
            if buffer is not None:
                # Send the processed file to the user
                with open('updated.xlsx', 'wb') as file:
                    file.write(buffer.getvalue())
                await query.message.answer("faylga yozildi", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

                await bot.send_document(chat_id=query.from_user.id, document=open('updated.xlsx', 'rb'))
                await query.message.answer("fayl yuborildi", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
                file_downloaded(user_id=query.from_user.id, user_firstname=query.from_user.first_name)
            else:
                await query.message.reply("❌ Faylni yozishda xatolik yuz berdi")
        else:
            await query.answer("Siz admin emassiz, fayl yuklolmaysiz!", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    except Exception as e:
        await query.message.reply(f"❌❓Возникло ошибка ! : <b>{str(e)}</b>\n")


users when click button in order to get updated file, they should be served by providing updated excel file

the solution has found. BufferedInputFile.from_file(file_path), and after downloading remove created excel file. It helped in my case
#ozgartirilgan excel_data dict ni yangi excel fayl yaratib , foydalanuvchiga yuborish hendleri
@file_router.callback_query(lambda c: c.data == "download_ip_file")
async def download_ip_file(query: CallbackQuery):
    try:
        if is_admin(query.from_user.id):
            await query.answer(" Faylni serverdan qabul qilib oling\n yuklanmoqda...",
                               reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
            file_path = f'ip_plan_file{datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")}.xlsx'

        # Write the DataFrames to the Excel file
        with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            for sheet_name, df in excel_data.items():
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

        # Check if the file was processed successfully
        if file_path is not None and os.path.exists(file_path):
            # Send the processed file to the user
            # Fetch the action before sending the file
            await query.bot.send_chat_action(
                chat_id=query.message.chat.id,
                action=ChatAction.UPLOAD_DOCUMENT,
            )
            await bot.send_document(query.from_user.id, BufferedInputFile.from_file(file_path))

             # Remove the file after sending it
            os.remove(file_path)

            file_downloaded(user_id=query.from_user.id, user_firstname=query.from_user.first_name)
        else:
            await query.message.reply("❌ Faylni yozishda xatolik yuz berdi")
    else:
        await query.answer("Siz admin emassiz, fayl yuklolmaysiz!", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        await query.message.answer("Siz admin emassiz, fayl yuklolmaysiz!", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
    await query.message.reply(f"❌❓Возникло ошибка ! : <b>{str(e)}</b>\n")
finally:
    # Always remove the file after the operation
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        os.remove(file_path)
        logging.info("Temporary file deleted.")
        await query.message.answer("Temporary file deleted.", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

